# how works createQueryBuilder and leftJoin?

Tags: doctrine-orm

I dont get how to make it work.

I have:

- a table `partner` with fields `id` and `name`
- a table `partner_address` with two fields: `id_partner` and `id_address`
- a table `address` with fields `id` and external key `id_town` which references `town(id)`
- a table `town` with fields `id`, a `name`, and `postal_code`

I want to select all partners that are in towns with specific `postal_code`
This query works:

```
SELECT p.nom, v.nom
FROM partner p
JOIN partner_address pa
ON pa.id_partner=p.id
JOIN address a
ON pa.id_address = a.id 
JOIN town t
ON a.id_town=t.id
WHERE t.postal_code='13480';
```

Now I want to "translate" it into Doctrine 2 full syntax, following [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html).

So I've made a custom repository:

`src/Society/Bundle/MyProjectBundle/Repository/PartnerRepository.php`

In this repository, I'm trying to create the corresponding function:

```
<?php

namespace HQF\Bundle\PizzasBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class PartenaireRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * Get all active partners from a given postal code.
     */
    public function findAllActiveByCp($cp)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->where('p.dateVFin IS NULL')
            ->andWhere('p.cp=:cp')
            ->addOrderBy('p.cp', 'DESC')
            ->setParameter('cp', $cp);
    }
}
```

Nota: the query in the code is **not the right one** but this code works in another custom repository I've made, so I'm trying to start from this code.

I'm trying something like this but it doesn't work:

```
public function findAllActiveByCp($cp)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
    return $qb
        ->leftJoin('partner_address pa ON pa.id_partner=p.id')
        ->leftJoin('address a ON pa.id_address = a.id')
        ->leftJoin('town t ON a.id_ville=t.id')
        ->where('p.dateVFin IS NULL')
        ->andWhere('t.cp=:cp')
        ->addOrderBy('t.cp', 'DESC')
        ->setParameter('cp', $cp);
}
```

I get this error:

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder::leftJoin(),
>   called in
>   /blabla/Repository/PartenaireRepository.php
>   on line 18 and defined in
>   /blabla/symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/QueryBuilder.php
>   line 767

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to join only properties, that the selected entity have.

In first parameter of `join()` or `leftJoin()` or `xxxJoin()` you pass the attribute name related to selected object, and in the second - alias for joined entity.

Try similar to this:

```
$q = $this->em()->createQueryBuilder();

$q->select(['item', 'itemContact'])
  ->from('ModuleAdmin\Entity\CustomerEntity', 'item')
  ->leftJoin('item.contacts', 'itemContact')
  ->andWhere($q->expr()->like('item.name', ':customerNameStart'));
```

Of course, the `CustomerEntity` contains `OneToMany` relation in field `contacts`.

Remember, that in select statement **you have to select the root entity** (in my example `CustomerEntity` aliased as `item`).

---

Edit by Olivier Pons to add how I found out the solution, and to mark this answer as valid, because it put me on the right track, thank you Adam!

In the file `PartenaireRepository.php` I've used the `createQueryBuilder('p')` properly. Here's how to make two joins in a row, using `createQueryBuilder()`:

```
class PartenaireRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    /** 
     * Retrieval of all partners given for a given postal code.
     */
    public function findAllActiveByCp($cp)
    {   
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->leftJoin('p.adresses', 'a')
            ->leftJoin('a.ville', 'v')
            ->where('v.cp=:cp')
            ->setParameter('cp', $cp);
    ... blabla
    }
}
```

Comment: I still have that problem with "ManyToOne". One item may have one or more contacts. So from my point of view it should be OneToMany, not ManyToOne. Am I right. And if not, have you a "simple way" to avoid this misunderstanding?

Comment: Yup, you have right. I have a "typo" in my answer, just edited :). In my code there is `OneToMany` of course. Nevertheless, hope i helped.

Remember that you are obliged to select the root entity.

Comment: You're right!! I'm on the right track: in my `PartenaireRepository.php` this works: `$this->createQueryBuilder('p') ->leftJoin('p.adresses', 'a');` but now if i want **another** join on addresses how can I do??

Comment: `->leftJoin('p.adresses', 'a')->leftJoin('a.something', 'sth')->leftJoin('sth.another', 'ano');` ...

Comment: I've edited your answer to add the right solution and check it as valid. Feel free to edit it again if I've made mistakes. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I believe for what you're doing, you will need to provide four arguments to the `leftJoin` method.

```
->leftJoin('partner_address', 'pa', 'ON', 'pa.id_partner = p.id')
```

So your query builder chain should look like this

```
public function findAllActiveByCp($cp)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
    return $qb
        ->leftJoin('partner_address', 'pa', 'ON', 'pa.id_partner = p.id')
        ->leftJoin('address', 'a', 'ON', 'pa.id_address = a.id')
        ->leftJoin('town', 't', 'ON', 'a.id_ville = t.id')
        ->where('p.dateVFin IS NULL')
        ->andWhere('t.cp=:cp')
        ->addOrderBy('t.cp', 'DESC')
        ->setParameter('cp', $cp)
    ;
}
```

Comment: I've tried but there's an error on the `->leftJoin('partner_address')`: `[Semantical Error] line 0, col 68 near 'partner_address': Error: Class 'partner_address' is not defined.`. I don't get that. Why should it be a "class"? It should be a database table, end of story!

Comment: Ah, do you have a Doctrine entity class for each table? ie, is there a `HQF\Bundle\PizzasBundle\Entity\PartnerAddress` that would map to the `partner_address` table? If so, replace `partner_address` with `PartnerAddress`.

Comment: and yeah I kinda agree, it should be a table and not a class, but I guess that's why it's called an ORM. If you prefer to use the QueryBuilder but with the tables directly, there's one available in the DBAL, but doesn't have all the features as the one in the ORM.

Comment: The other problem is that the table `partner_address` is already declared in the entity `Partner` php file, in the property `addresses` (which is a `@ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Address")` property). This is getting on my nerves, because there are different ways to do the same thing, and it's never really clear which one is the best. Maybe I should do this `findAllActiveByCp($cp)` the `Town` entities, and create something like `findAllActivePartnersByCp($cp)` or something...