# Cannot select entity through identification variables in repository

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following query. The query is inside my InstagramShopPicture

```
$queryBuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
                    ->select('p.id, p.caption, p.price, p.lowresimageurl, p.medresimageurl, p.highresimageurl, p.numberoflikes, p.numberofdislikes, shop.id, shop.username, shop.fullname, contact, category')
                    ->leftJoin('p.shop', 'shop')
                    ->leftJoin('shop.contact', 'contact')
                    ->leftJoin('p.category', 'category')
                    ->leftJoin('category.pictureTopCategory', 'pictureTopCategory')
                    ->leftJoin('category.pictureFirstLevelCategory', 'pictureFirstLevelCategory')
                    ->leftJoin('category.pictureSecondLevelCategory', 'pictureSecondLevelCategory')
                    ->where('p.isLocked = false')
                    ->andWhere('p.isStyleInspiration = false')
                    ->andWhere('shop.isLocked = false');
```

I am however getting the following error:

```
QueryException: [Semantical Error] line 0, col -1 near 'SELECT p.id,': Error: Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias
```

any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: I've deleted my answer, because I've find this for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878237/doctrine-cannot-select-entity-through-identification-variables-without-choosing Hope this solve you problem!

Answer (score 1):

After some research here in SO I came to this solution. Try adding

```
->from('YourEntityNameForP', 'p')
->from('YourEntityNameForShop', 'shop')
```

to  `createQueryBuilder`

Since I'm not familiar neither with Symfony 2, nor with Doctrine 2 and just trying to help!

Credits here: [Doctrine: Cannot select entity through identification variables without choosing at least one root entity alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878237/doctrine-cannot-select-entity-through-identification-variables-without-choosing)

Comment: got a different error now  line 0, col 169 near 'contact, p.category,': Error: Invalid PathExpression. Must be a StateFieldPathExpression.

Comment: I'm not familiar with symfony, so is there a way you could print the generated here? You also have a comma `,` after `p.category` which should not be there

Comment: A db schema will also be helpful maybe

Comment: @adit As I search a little bit it seems like your query is prety messed up, so maybe try asking another question, giving a db schema and what you want to achieve with your query.

Comment: how does asking another question solves the issue here... and what's messed up about it

Comment: Take a look at `leftJoin` docs: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html. `join` works as you joining two tables by some field, your leftJoins are wrong. But as far as I don't know what you want to get with the query and do not have db schema, I cannot help

Comment: @adit Take a look at this, too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552333/how-works-createquerybuilder-and-leftjoin

Answer (score -1):

Seems you are trying to make joins without using aliases for your tables.

This chould cause you a lot of problems, particularly when column names are identical

```
     ->leftJoin('p.category', 'category') // aliasing
    ->leftJoin('category.pictureTopCategory', 'pictureTopCategory') // table name
```

One time you are using table name, next you are using aliases !! Choose only one approach of them

Comment: so how do I solve this, I don't quite get your explanation sorry.. I am using an alias with the same name as the column name?

Comment: No. I mean you are one time using a table explicity to access its column `category.pictureTopCategory`, while in the same time using alias for table name `p.category`. SQL does not accept this. Either use table names for ALL tables, or use aliases for ALL tables.

Comment: This query is invalid for example:
`select * from Item i JOIN ItemCategory ON i.itemcategory = ItemCategory.id` while these two ones are valid:
`select * from Item i JOIN ItemCategory ic ON i.itemcategory = ic.id` and `select * from Item JOIN ItemCategory ON Item.itemcategory = ItemCategory.id`

Comment: I tried changing so that the alias is not the same as the tableName however it still gives me the same error

Comment: Try removing some parts of your query, and see when does it break